# How do I get the plasmoid repository

Tags: kubuntu, kde, ppa, repository, plasma

I had a load of plasmoids, beginning with plasma-widget- and kde-applet and kde-plasmoid-, which I think I had added from a PPA, but I can't for the life of me find which one it is (I did a fresh install). I have already tried the backports (first PPA I added anyway), but it isn't the one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Plasmoids / Plasma-widgets**

The Ubuntu is using the plasma-widget-* as the package name: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?38465-Plasmoids-are-now

**KDE plasmoids - from the Ubuntu repositories and from the Kubuntu developers PPA**

[image]

```
:~$ apt-cache show plasma-widgets-workspace

Description: plasma widgets and containments for the KDE Plasma Workspace
 This package contains standard Plasma widgets and containments shipped in the
 KDE base workspace module. They provide such basic desktop functionality as
 the panel, task manager, application laucher, clock and more. The default KDE
 Workspace is a combination of these visual components.
 .
 This package also includes the default animator used by the main KDE Plasma
 Desktop shell.
 .
 This package is part of the KDE workspace module.
Homepage: http://www.kde.org/


:~$ apt-cache show plasma-widgets-addons

Description: additional widgets for Plasma
 This package contains additional Plasma widgets shipped in the Plasma
 addons module. Install it if you want a variety of widgets on your Plasma
 desktop.
 .
 This package provides the following widgets:
  * Binary Clock
  * Black Board
...
  * Weather Forecast
  * Web Slice
 .
 This package is part of the KDE Plasma addons module.
Homepage: http://plasma.kde.org/
```

**Plasmoids (binaries) source is from the KDE-apps or somewhere - The Ubuntu repositories and the Kubuntu developers PPA have the package**

Example: plasma-widget-smooth-tasks

```
:~$ apt-cache show plasma-widget-smooth-tasks

Description: alternate task manager plasma widget
 This task manager replacement shows only task icons
 to increase the free space of the panel.
Homepage: https://bitbucket.org/flupp/smooth-tasks-fork/
```

**Third party ppa**

Example: plasma-widget-daisy -> PPA search: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=plasma-widget-daisy

**Plasma scrips**

The plasma scripts can be downloaded/installed from the add-widgets action:

[image]